Which of the following insertion sort algorithms do you think is faster？
void insertion_sort_1(int *begin, int *end) {
    for (int *cur = begin + 1; cur < end; ++cur) {
        int tmp = *cur;
        int *pos = cur;
        for (int *i = cur; i > begin && *(i - 1) > tmp; --i) {
            *i = *(i - 1);
            pos = i - 1;
        }
        *pos = tmp;
    }
}

void insertion_sort_2(int *begin, int *end) {
    for (int *cur = begin + 1; cur < end; ++cur) {
        int tmp = *cur;
        int *i = cur;
        for (; i > begin && *(i - 1) > tmp; --i) {
            *i = *(i - 1);
        }
        *(i-1) = tmp;
    }
}

I initially thought the second insertion sort algorithm is faster,but after the experiment it was found that the second insertion sort algorithm is slower!
Result:



algorithm
run time




insertion_sort_1
2245 ms


insertion_sort_2
2899 ms



Test code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h> 

#define SMALL_N 5000
#define MIDDLE_N 100000
#define BIG_N 10000000

__attribute__((constructor))
void __init__Rand__() {
    srand(time(0));
}

bool check(int* begin, int* end) {
    int* cur = begin;
    for(; cur < end - 1; ++cur) {
        if(*cur > *(cur + 1)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

#define TEST(func, begin, end){\
        printf("Test %s : ", #func);\
        int *tmp = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * (end - begin));\
        memcpy(tmp, begin, sizeof(int) * (end - begin));\
        long long b = clock();\
        func(tmp, tmp - end + begin);\
        long long e = clock();\
        if(check(tmp, tmp - end + begin)) printf("\tOK");\
        else printf("\tWrong");\
        printf("\t%lld ms\n", (e - b) * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);\
        free(tmp);\
    }

int *geneArr(unsigned n) {
    int* arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int tmp = rand() % 10000;
        arr[i] = tmp;
    }
    return arr;
}

void swap(int* a, int* b) {
    if(a == b) return;
    int c = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = c;
}

// ================================================================================================

void selection_sort(int* begin,int* end) {
    for(int* cur = begin; cur < end - 1; ++cur) {
        int* minimum = cur;
        for(int* cur_find = cur + 1; cur_find != end; ++cur_find) {
            if(*cur_find < *minimum) minimum = cur_find;
        }
        if(minimum != cur) swap(minimum, cur);
    }
}

void insertion_sort_1(int *begin, int *end) {
    for (int *cur = begin + 1; cur < end; ++cur) {
        int tmp = *cur;
        int *pos = cur;
        for (int *i = cur; i > begin && *(i - 1) > tmp; --i) {
            *i = *(i - 1);
            pos = i - 1;
        }
        *pos = tmp;
    }
}

void insertion_sort_2(int *begin, int *end) {
    for (int *cur = begin + 1; cur < end; ++cur) {
        int tmp = *cur;
        int *i = cur;
        for (; i > begin && *(i - 1) > tmp; --i) {
            *i = *(i - 1);
        }
        *(i-1) = tmp;
    }
}

int main() {
//  int N=SMALL_N;
    int N=MIDDLE_N;
//  int N=BIG_N;
    int* arr = geneArr(N);

    TEST(insertion_sort_1, arr, arr + N);
    TEST(insertion_sort_2, arr, arr + N);

    free(arr); 
    return 0;
}

In the second algorithm,I have reduce the assignment operator,but it becomes slower.I want to know why?Thanks!

"... do you think is faster" -  Why should we guess? We'd measure with our data if needed. "why?" - compiler optimizations would be my guess. At what compiler optimization are you compiling? Max?

As written, I didn't find any reason for the compiler to leave any calculations in the final program.  Parts you think are measured may actually be just removed since there's nothing inspecting the result.

Unrelated: if(a == b) return; is a suboptimization. Most times swap is called, you want a swap to be done. Those few times your swap function is called with a pointer to the same int, just swap the pointed out ints anyway - nothing will happen. That said, use std::swap instead.

The code is C, nothing shown is C++. #define TEST(func, begin, end){... looks awful. You seem need to learn function pointers.

I disabled optimization : $ gcc  -O0 test.c , but result : Test insertion_sort_1 :  5317 ms ; Test insertion_sort_2 : 7825 ms .

Yes , even if the two values are equal, the swap operation is performed without any side effects.

@user24402200 That was merely an observation. Not a solution. Don't write code like that.
